# Basic CSS opacity

Tags: css, button, menu, webshop

I'm using SaaS for building my own webshop. The problem is that i dont know any code. I wish to make my menu bar look more stylish. The SaaS platform offers CSS editing but i can't change the html. 
The current menu bar has this css;

```
#menu {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background: #005775;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0; 
}
```

How can I make this better looking. I tried changing the opacity, but every time i add the word opacity the code breaks and the memu disappears.

My current Design looks like this;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSD5F.jpg
I would really like to make the Menu bar a bit less rough and make it look more friendly.

Sorry for my horrible grammar and lack of knowledge.

Comment: Can you show what you tried ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "better looking"? And, we can only see some codes, not the visual demonstration, so we can't really give anything on how to make it "better looking"

Comment: Without knowing what would constitute 'better looking', I find it difficult to offer suggestions. There's no accounting for taste!

Comment: This is amazing, so many people are trying to help. 
I have uploaded a picture of my website so you can see it. The menu bar looks really rough and unfriendly. Thats why i want to make it softer.

http://imgur.com/a/ptSuA  

@O.Paquay

Comment: it's just a matter of taste. tell us exactly and more specific what you want it to look like and we will help you. otherwise we can't 'guess' what you want

Answer (score 0):

try using 
`background-color:rgba()` instead of opacity
this adds transparency to the menu bar.

example

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

the last value adds transparency.

Answer (score 0):

> When you added opacity to `#menu`, it affect on All his Childrens and menu disappears.you must use of `background-color:rgba()` or `background-color:hsla()`

```
#005775 = rgba(0, 87, 117, 1.0)
#005775 = hsla(195, 100%, 23%, 1.0)
```

So :

```css
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  background:rgba(0, 87, 117, 0.3);/*/ I use 0.3 /*/
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">I Am Menu</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and time. 
The code works, but it does not give the effect i wanted. Sorry, i think i'm not good at explaining what i wanted. 

" This is amazing, so many people are trying to help. 
I have uploaded a picture of my website so you can see it. The menu bar looks really rough and unfriendly. Thats why i want to make it softer.

http://imgur.com/a/ptSuA "

Answer (score 0):

Try this. As said by others, this will reduce the opacity of the text in the menu too.

```
#menu {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background: #005775;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  opacity: 0.5; // Change this value between 0(transparent) -> 1(100% visible);
}
```